# Set of all countably infinite strings over a finite alphabet >1

Tags: formal-languages

Is the set of all countably infinite strings over a finite alphabet that contains more than one letter countably infinite?

Comment: What is a "countably infinite string"?

Comment: An infinite string over the alphabet that can be counted. Hence, can be sorted in an ascending order.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that the order doesn't even have to be ascending, any order will do.

Comment: You say "over a finite alphabet" which already implies that your underlying alphabet is countable. So, no need to use the word "countably" (which may be confusing), simply "infinite strings" would be enough.

Comment: Agreed, "infinite strings", that are by the way "countable".

Comment: @fade2black This is completely standard and not at all confusing. A countably infinite string is string whose positions are indexed by some countable ordinal (i.e., a function $\alpha\to\Sigma$ for some countable $\alpha$). "Countable" isn't redundant: one could  have a string whose positions are indexed by some uncountable ordinal (e.g., a function $\omega_1\to\Sigma$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby by "standard" do you mean it is given as a standard definition at the beginning of every textbook in Computability theory and formal languages?  I have just Googled "countably infinite string" and didn't find anything that defined it formally. I have looked up in Sipser's, Hopcroft's, Cutland's, M .Davis' books,  in the "Dragon" book, couldn't find anything that defines it. While you can define it as you describe in your comment, I don't think it is a "standard" one.

Comment: @fade2black Books on computability and compilers generally consider only finite strings since. Anything that talks about, e.g., [Büchi automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton), which are widely used in formal verification, will mention countably infinite words, though they often only consider $\omega$-words (those where the countable length is the cardinality of the natural numbers).

Comment: @fade2black For example, the Wikipedia page on [$\omega$-automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-automaton) defines "infinite words" and it's a tiny step from there to "countably infinite words".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I got you. Thanks for references.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ and the set of all infinite length strings over $\Sigma$. Then this set is of course infinite, but uncountable which can be easily proved by the diagonalization argument.

Comment: Thanks, you know what I don't like about easily proved diagonalization arguments? It's that their ease is a matter of perspective. What's easy there is not so easy here! Any way I was thinking to prove it this way: Since we cannot order the sets in any manner, then they are uncountable.If we take two strings s1 and s2 when s2>s1 we can plot a string s3 that will be between them by simply adding characters to s1or removing them from s2.. So how about that diagonal argument of yours?

Comment: Assume that this set is countable, i.e., its elements (strings) can be enumerated as $s_1, s_2,\dots $. Then you can construct a new infinite string $s$ which differs from each $s_i$ in $i$-th position by the following rule: if $i$th symbol of $s_i$ is $0$ then let $i$-th symbol of $s$ be $1$, and  let $i$-th symbol of $s$ be $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Yes, now I see what you ment by easily proved.

Answer (score 2):

Take the alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ and consider strings whose positions are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ (also known as $\omega$-words).  There is a one-to-one correspondence between these strings and subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ given by $x_0x_1x_2\dots \leftrightarrow \{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid x_i=1\}$. Therefore, there are as many $\omega$-words as there are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and this is an uncountable number.

This holds for any countably infinite word length.

Comment: The question says "set of all *countably infinite* strings...". Doesnt that mean the set is already known to be *countably infinite* (and we have nothing to prove) ? Am I missing something and sounding stupid?

Comment: @anir The strings have countably infinite length; the question is how many of these strings exist.

Comment: ohh so its "strings of countably infinite length", but not "countably infinite *number* of strings"! **(Q1)** What does countable means in "countably infinite length". (Length is single value not an infinite set whose elements we can count.) **(Q2)** I guess all languages on non-singleton alphabet with infinite length strings are uncountable, right?